# Alabama: College refusing to award Minor due to unclear/vague wording in policy

Tags: academia, administrative-law

Location: Alabama, USA.

I have recently completed all coursework required for my degree, including a cluster in (name changed) Basketweaving. A cluster consists of 6 specified courses (it is essentially the same thing as a minor, however, due to legal/administrative reasons at the university, they cannot legally call it a minor). One of these courses (call it UB200, intro to underwater basketweaving, course name changed for privacy), I received a C in, which is a passing grade and a satisfaction as a prerequisite.

As this was the only C I received for my cluster, I found a form on the university website called a "Course Forgiveness form". This form states the following relevant points. There are others I can provide if requested, but I do not see their relevance to this post.

Students may forgive any three courses. provided that they are **not required for their major** (emphasis mine).

- Any forgiven courses and the assigned grades remain on the transcript, but the grades are not calculated into the students cumulative grade point average.
- Forgiveness is retroactive but must be done before graduation.
- Forgiveness cannot be unforgiven.

The same relevant points were verbatim on the course forgiveness form that I signed and gave to the registrar. No additional points were added or stated in this form.

In short, this form allows for a student to have 3 grades removed from their GPA calculation, but the course remains on their transcript. I took advantage of this to have the grade for UB200 removed from my GPA calculation.

When it came time for my degree audit, I was informed that UB200 could not be used for ANY credit whatsoever. I appealed the decision, on the basis that the wording explicitly states that course forgiveness cannot be used for courses required for a major. It says nothing concerning a cluster or minor. I asked if an exception could be made to the policy due to the unclear wording, and I be allowed to "take back" the form and have the C reinstated on my transcript, and receive credit for the cluster. This too was denied.

My appeals have been escalated to the provost, and all appeals have been met with the same response: (paraphrased)

> Your request to undo the course forgiveness has been denied.

When I talked to the provost concerning this, they explained that "they can't list EVERYTHING that the form applies or doesn't apply to, so I should have known what it meant."

I have asked each level to provide me a reference to any wording that explicitly states what they claim. They refuse to acknowledge the vague wording of the form, or provide a reference to an explanation of why the form also applies to my cluster. I have escalated this to the highest level at the university, and have been met with the same responses.

Due to their response of "we can't list everything that this applies to", I present Exhibit A: the pass/fail policy. This policy states the following:

> A student is limited to 12 semester hours of credit on a P-F basis over the course of the degree. Courses listed on the Program of Study (major, minor, cognate, track, cluster, specialization, option and concentration) may not be taken P-F.

This policy explicitly spells out all types of awards/degrees. The inconsistency between this policy and the course forgiveness policy would seem to imply that the course forgiveness for credit policy explicitly applies to a major only.

I feel as though I am wronged. What type of lawyer (if any) would best be suited to help me pursue action against the university in order to receive credit for this? Is "you know what we mean" a valid argument from the university?

Comment: Is this a state school or private?

Comment: Typically the form would only have an unofficial summary of relevant information about forgiveness, and the full policy would be contained in the university's course catalog or similar document.  Have you checked the catalog?  If it says something like "no credit is awarded for forgiven courses", then your case is probably shot.

Comment: @bdb484 this is a state school

Comment: @NateEldredge I have 1) checked the course catalog 2) searched the university policies for relevant information 3) asked the university to show the wording of a policy that states course forgiveness does not count for credit. All three of these approaches have resulted in no results.

Comment: Following up on Nate's point, does a forgiven course count towards the credits you need to graduate? In other words, does forgiveness have the same effect as dropping the course -- no grade or credit. PS If you look at your transcript, you should be able to tell whether you are getting the credits from the course. PS Nice question.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to me that the point you're focusing on is not the most relevant one.  The rules on the form seem to have been applied properly: the course was not required for your major, and so you *were* permitted to have it forgiven, and it was ignored in your GPA calculation, and everything else stated on the form happened.  The issue is what wasn't stated on the form: can a forgiven course still be used to fulfill graduation requirements?  You thought the answer was yes, the university intended the answer to be no.

Comment: Normally the intended purpose of policies like "forgiveness" is that you have the course removed from your GPA, **and then you take it again** to earn the credit, or take some other course fulfilling the same requirements.  It's more like a retroactive drop than anything. The exception for major-required courses is that they want your GPA to reflect *all* the work you did in major courses, even courses that you did poorly in and needed to retake.

Comment: @NateEldredge from what I can tell, the original idea behind the course forgiveness is such: Bob enters into the school in engineering. He takes Cal A, cal B, and gets C's in both of them and realizes he's terrible at math and could not possibly succeed in engineering. He switches to an art major, which does not require calculus, and uses course forgiveness to get his Cal A/B taken out of his GPA, as they are no longer required by his major. I did approximately the same thing. I switched from Underwater Basketweaving to a new degree, and my new degree did not require UB200. (continued)

Comment: Because the course was no longer required by my major, I was of the understanding that it was okay to use as the policy explicitly stated only the word major, unlike other policies which listed all types of awards. This feels like an edge case that was not accounted for in the original policy.

Comment: @Justaguy reviewing my transcript, the course remains on the transcript, but is listed as `UB200: XC`. It is counted under the semester's "Attempted Hours". It is not counted in the number of hours I earned for that semester and not factored into the GPA. So yes, it appears that the *outcome* of the form is similar to dropping the class but keeping the grade on the transcript. The difference between this and dropping it is I took (for example) UB300, which requires UB200 as a pre-req. If I had dropped UB200, I would not have been able to take UB300.

Comment: @blackbrandt But it *was* "OK to use" course forgiveness on a non-major class - you already did that successfully. The policy was applied properly, it's just that the effect wasn't what you expected. The only relevant question is if it's stated anywhere that forgiven courses do not count for credit, which you have been unable to find so far.

Comment: @blackbrandt So it seems, as Nate put it, your case is shot. Forgiveness effectively lets you drop the course after you took it. Once a course is forgiven, it's as if you never took it. Since you can only count courses you take towards majors or clusters, a forgiven course can't count. The real problem is that you misunderstood how forgiveness works. The question is who is responsible for your confusion.

Comment: I understand what happened due to the outcome of the form. I am trying to argue that the form and policy was misleading and the policy wording did not accurately reflect how the forgiveness would affect my credit for the course. I'm trying to argue to the university that due to the unclear wording and the edge case it applies to, they should allow me to undo the form and award me the cluster.

Comment: You may be vastly overestimating the value of any sort of "minor" or "not-a-minor-but-kind-of-a-minor"; it's the sort of thing you might appeal within the university if you really have a solid argument, which it seems you do not, but any lawyer's fees to resolve it are going to eat up the value you're fighting for immediately.

Comment: @BryanKrause I understand the cost/benefit point you make. However, I do have an lawyer acquaintance who has agreed to help me out with this case at low/no cost (I figured out about this after this question was asked). If I can't win against the university, I'll just have my resume state "completed coursework for UB" instead of "cluster in UB", which isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The university gives you no reason to think that the statement "Students may forgive any three courses, provided that they are not required for their major" means "Students may forgive any three courses, provided that they are not used to satisfy any university requirements". They also clearly state that "Forgiveness cannot be unforgiven". The provost's statement that "Your request to undo the course forgiveness has been denied" is either non-responsive or indicates that someone messed up in handing him the complaint, since your petition was at least initially to enforce only the major-related restriction (rather than the revised unwritten version), and undoing forgiveness is as you know not possible. Thus the provost has not denied your appeal of the "follow your own rules" petition.

Insofar as nothing in the university documentation (at least that available online) indicates that this is the equivalent of dropping a course after the end of the class, and that everything indicates that this simply removes the specified courses from the computation of GPA, it's not reasonable to expect that a person could divine some other intention. But: as you noted, you also don't get credit for the class. So the rationale of denying you use of the course in satisfaction of the requirement is reasonable, what's not reasonable (in the ordinary sense of the word) is the conclusion that "they can't list EVERYTHING that the form applies or doesn't apply to" and that you "should have known what it meant". Your legal recourse would be to file a lawsuit. However, suing a university is sort of a last-resort action, since they didn't clearly violate the law. If you had been aware that you would not get credit for the course, you "should have known" (to use the legal phase) that the effectively-dropped course would not be usable for *any* purpose. You can argue in court that the university had a duty to inform you of these important procedural details which do not appear to be described anywhere. If you spoke to an advisor, the advisor would have been negligent in not telling you of this important information. So in theory, you could sue and get then to remedy the situation (most likely by reversing the forgiveness).

The main problem that you will face is that your petition and your appeal were considered, and it was found that you were not wronged. The courts generally accept the results of university-internal appeals systems, unless there is a clear violation of law or egregious departure from stated procedure.